# Modal winform not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, controls

I have a .NET winforms application developed using VS 2010 (.NET 4.0) and OS is Windows 7. In the solution I have a simple form which consists of a simple a calendar control. This form is invoked on a button click from 2 different forms. The call on button click is as follows:

```
// Parent Form
public class ParentForm : Form
{
// Button click event handler is as follows:

void btnCalendarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // ...other code
   MyStatisClass.ShowCalendar();
}
}

//Calendar Form
public class CalendarForm : Form
{
// And the ShowCalendar method is as under..
public static void ShowCalendar()
{
using (CalendarForm frm = new CalendarForm())
{
   if(frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { SelectedDate = frm.LastSelectedDate; }
}
}

}
```

Now I am having 2 copies of the parent Form, which are almost similar in design and code. However, on the button click, in one form, the Calendar shows up where as on the button click of the other form, it opens up, but does not display itself. I can see it however in the task bar and have to close it without selecting anything by clicking on the cross in the task bar itself as it never shows itself on the screen. I checked all the tab order for the controls, tried doing a BringToFront on the calendar form and SendToBack on the Parent Form, tried to check for cross threads using InvokeRequired property, yet I am not seeing the form. Also, I put try catch in every possible place to see if an exception occurs; but it is not hit and in fact the form is opened just fine. Kindly let me know if anything is missing that is prohibiting me from showing this form?

Thanks,
Bhushan

Comment: Seems inplausable from the posted code, your problem is int that "almost similar in design".

Comment: Are you trying to show 2 dialogs at once?

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the below code because your static method is in CalendarForm. I dont know what your static class is doing but you can call it directly as below.

```
MyStatisClass.ShowCalendar(); change to below
CalendarForm .ShowCalendar();
```

The problem here is that you have used **using** Statement which disposes the object automatically after scope ends. So remove the using statement and it will work fine.

I will suggest you that have a look and read over "using statement" in msdn.

```
public static void ShowCalendar()
{
   //using (CalendarForm frm = new CalendarForm())
   //{
     if(frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { SelectedDate = frm.LastSelectedDate; }
   //}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Putting a using around a modal form is quite OK and usually the best practice.

Comment: Totally Agreed! But with the current scenario "using" statement will not allow you to show up. Then you have to certainly rethink about the design.

Comment: But not randomly change things.

Comment: See if someone is a newbie and don't know the usage of "using" how can he think of design perspective.That's why I mentioned in my answer that "have a look and read over using statement in msdn". The sole perspective here is to help them so that they can overcome and learn more.

Comment: Dear All. I know the purpose of using statement quite well. Here the call to the Calendar form is just encapsulated in a static method and this works perfectly fine in one of the calling form while the same code just does not allow the form to be shown when called from the second form. As I mentioned before, the Form is created and loaded as well; as I can see it in the task bar. However, it does not show the UI so as to do some useful work. Is the Z-order of the 2 Forms need to be checked? @Pan4321, I tried your suggestion, it did not work for me. I am not quite sure what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Incidentally, the issue still exists, but I have identified the cause; atleast it appears that way. The thing is, the Form that holds the Monthcalendar control, has a border style set to None and few other variables and properties set in the designer code. As I mentioned before, the other form was able to show it, but on a different machine (windows 7). My machine also has windows 7; however I had disabled all the styles to optimize the performance and I was not able to display the form. I just enabled the styles on my machine and the calendar was displayed. So, I think this should be the cause. However, if this is the cause, then next question comes to my mind is why? Anyone having a clue, please share. 
Thanks,
Bhushan.